# Simple excel formula equivalent

Tags: javascript, excel

I have a simple excel formula I am trying to replicate in javascript but am a newbie and can't seem to get it to work!

Excel Formula:

```
=((D6*D7)/3.6)+(D7*D7)/(254*(D8+0.01*D9))
```

Java Script:

```
= (D6 * D7) / 3.6 + (D7 * D7) / (254 * (D8 + 0.01 * D9));
```

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Where do you get the values for `D6`- `D9` from? What's their type? What's the current and the expected result?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Have you defined the variables `D6`, `D7` and so on? Also you can use the `console.log` function to show the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Justin,
I already had the variables defined, I was just questioning the formula. After trial and error I found that the D8 addition was causing the problem. The final successful outcome was:

    = ((D6 * D7) / 3.6) + (D7 * D7) / (254 * (0.01 * D9 + +D8))

Answer (score 1):

you should define the value of D6, D7, D8 and D9 at first, like:

```
var D6 = 3;
var D7 = 5;
var D8 = 9;
var D9 = 10;

var result = (D6 * D7) / 3.6 + (D7 * D7) / (254 * (D8 + 0.01 * D9));
```